# GTA San Andreas iOS - can't get into fast food stores

Tags: ios, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I can't enter a food store in gta San Andreas on the iPad , eg: burger shot, clucking bell. There isn't a yellow triangle at the door where it supposed to be.

Answer (score 3):

These are disabled on the iOS version of the game to help with running the game smoothly.